# How to log out when using Net::SFTP

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get started with [`Net::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP), but I wasn't able to find in its documentation or in the documentation for [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl), how we're supposed to log out of the SFTP server.

What am I missing?

Is logout handled by garbage control?

Comment: @Borodin , thanks for the edit

Comment: You're welcome. Most people take a parental attitude to their posts and curse me for even touching them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't.**

I've looked at the source code for both [Net::SFTP](https://metacpan.org/source/DBROBINS/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm) and Net::SSH::Perl. Neither of them has a `DESTROY` method, so there is no explicit cleanup being done. There are also no `disconnect` or `quit` or similar.

Net::SSH::Perl has a [`sub _disconnect` which is empty](https://metacpan.org/source/Net::SSH::Perl#L267). It's [called by `sub fatal_disconnect`](https://metacpan.org/source/Net::SSH::Perl#L269). [`fatal_disconnect` is used](https://metacpan.org/source/DBROBINS/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm#L93) by Net::SFTP in case an SFTP request failed. But that's it. Nothing else.

The objects get cleaned up by Perl as soon as they go out of scope.

```
{
    my $sftp = Net::SFTP->connect; # example
    # do stuff...
}

# here it has been cleaned up and DESTROY was called on it
```

But since there is no code, nothing else happens. I cannot find code that tells the SSH to log out. Maybe it just times out. We would have to look at the server logs to see what happens.

Comment: Yes, same here. Thanks for looking, i couldn't believe something this basic would be overlooked. So depending on how long the program lives, connections may be timed out by the server, or they will be closed when the program terminates and Unix releases its resources.

If the server times out the connection, i think some resources still are kept on the client side (the client side of the socket). So a  long lived program may be able to make many connections and eventually starve the system, because they are not properly released.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I don't know enough about SSH to say anything about it.